# How to extract the grammar productions rules given bracketed parses?

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, context-free-grammar

I have a sample sentence. "Open the door." that I parsed a sentence to get the bracketed parse output as below.

> (S (VP (VB open) (NP (DT the) (NN door))) (. .))

I need to extract the CFG grammar rules that produce the parsed output.
I can manually write them out as such:

```
grammar = CFG.fromstring("""   
S -> VP NP   
NP -> Det N   
VP -> V   
Det ->'the '   
N -> 'door'   
V -> 'Open'   
""")
```

But it's time consuming, how do I produce the grammar rules given the bracketed parsed automatically?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more clear about what you need: The first sentence says you need the parenthesised form, the second one suggests you want to output the portions of the underlying grammar which fired for this sentence.

Comment: There might be some confusion here, judging from your consistently typing "formstring" instead of "fromstring". The format you are looking for is not a parse tree, but rather it's a grammar specification (it's one of the parser's inputs, not its output). So I doubt that there is an automatic solution to that already.

Comment: Yes I corrected the confusion. It  is fromstring. I understand it is a grammar specification that is used an an input. Is there a work around to create such specification given a parse tree? That will save me some time and effort. Not only by NLTK but by any other method. If no such ready-made solution exist;  Is it possible to create one?

Comment: What is your input? What is your desired output? It's unclear what you're asking. You have to a little more clearer so that we can help you =)

Comment: Are you trying to extract CFG rules from the parsers output? If so, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tree.py#L341

Comment: @alvas Yes, I think that's exactly what (s)he's looking for. You should put it in an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks lenz! The original question was a little fuzzy and i didn't understand what he/she needed.

Comment: @Programmer_nltk please ask another question if you need more answers on a related but not the same question. I'm going to rollback your edits. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **Tree.productions()** method to get CFG rules from Tree.

**Example:**

```
from nltk import Tree

t = Tree.fromstring("(S (VP (VB open) (NP (DT the) (NN door))) (. .))")
print t.productions()
```

**Output:**

```
[S -> VP ., VP -> VB NP, VB -> 'open', NP -> DT NN, DT -> 'the', 
 NN -> 'door', . -> '.']
```

For more information check - [NLTK Tree Productions](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.Tree.productions)

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to create the rules from a bracketed parsed, you can use [`Tree.productions()`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.tree.Tree.productions)

```
>>> from nltk import Tree
>>> t = Tree.fromstring("(S (NP (D the) (N dog)) (VP (V chased) (NP (D the) (N cat))))")
>>> t.productions()
[S -> NP VP, NP -> D N, D -> 'the', N -> 'dog', VP -> V NP, V -> 'chased', NP -> D N, D -> 'the', N -> 'cat']
```

The `Tree.productions()` will return a list of [`nltk.grammar.Productions`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/grammar.py#L236) objects:

```
>>> type(t.productions()[0])
<class 'nltk.grammar.Production'>
```

To get the rules into a string form, use the `Production.unicode_repr`:

```
>>> t.productions()[0].unicode_repr()
u'S -> NP VP'
```

To the get the string representation of the grammar learnt from bracketed parse:

```
>>> from nltk import Tree
>>> t = Tree.fromstring("(S (NP (D the) (N dog)) (VP (V chased) (NP (D the) (N cat))))")
>>> grammar_from_parse = "\n".join([rule.unicode_repr() for rule in t.productions()])
>>> print grammar_from_parse
S -> NP VP
NP -> D N
D -> 'the'
N -> 'dog'
VP -> V NP
V -> 'chased'
NP -> D N
D -> 'the'
N -> 'cat'
```